# C++: The order of std::cout

Tags: c++

Here, I wrote a simple Queue Class Template:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"

template <class T> class Queue {
private:
    struct Node {
        T value;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node *first, *last;
public:

    Queue () { //Initialization
        first = 0;
        last = 0;
    };

    void push(T value) { //Put new value into Queue
        Node *p = new Node;
        p->value = value;

        if (!first) //If Queue is not empty
            first = p;
        else
            last->next = p;

        last = p; //Put the value to the last of the Queue
    };

    T get() { //Get the first value of the Queue
        return (first) ? first->value : NULL;
    };

    T pop() { //Take the first value out of Queue
        T result = first->value;
        Node *temp = first;
        first = first->next;
        delete temp;
        return result;
    };
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Queue<int> bag;
    bag.push(1); //Bag has value 1
    bag.push(2); //Bag has values: 1, 2

    std::cout << bag.get() << '\n' << bag.pop() << '\n' << bag.pop();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

There is a problem - the output is:

```
0
2
1

/*
Correct output should be:
1
1
2
*/
```

When I debug the `std::cout` line, I found out that program call `bag.pop()` at the right most first, then the other `bag.pop()`, at last the `bag.get()`.
Is that the right order?

Comment: The order is unspecified, if you need a specific order separate your cout statement into three pieces. `std::cout << bag.get() << '\n'; std::cout << bag.pop() << '\n'; std::cout << bag.pop();`

Comment: If you searched, you would find some answers: [cout << order of call to functions it prints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/cout-order-of-call-to-functions-it-prints/2129242#2129242) & [Order of evaluation of arguments using std::cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout)

Comment: What if the template type `T` is not a pointer? Then you can't return `NULL` in the `get` function (unless `T` is a type that can be implicitly created from the integer `0`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
T get() { //Get the first value of the Queue
    return (!first) ? first->value : NULL;
};
```

This is backwards. Drop the `!`. You are saying "if `first` is *not* non-null, (ie if `first` *is* null), use it.

That said, the order of evaluation of arguments to a function is unspecified (the compiler can evaluate the arguments in any order it feels like, as long as they are all done before the function itself starts). That is `get()`, `pop()` and `pop()` can be called in any order. Call them as separate statements:

```
int a = bag.get();
int b = bag.pop();
int c = bag.pop();
std::cout << a << b << c;
```

Comment: Thank you. I fix that mistake but the program thrown exception because the first->value has no value to return after program call the other two `bag.pop()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
T get() { //Get the first value of the Queue
    return (!first) ? first->value : NULL;
};
```

You return `NULL` if `first` is valid. This gets interpreted as zero. You should inverse your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, it's unspecified when calculate function of argument. take this simple test, you will get what's that mean.

```
#include <iostream>
int b(void) {std::cout<<3<<std::endl; return 3;}
int c(void) {std::cout<<4<<std::endl; return 4;}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int d = b() + c();
  std::cout<<d<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

so you will get 3 4 5 or 4 3 5.

Answer (score -1):

first look at : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

std::cout take value from left to right.

Comment: It outputs the results from left to right. It evaluates its operands in an unspecified order, which is what the OP is asking about.