# Why cout gives me a result in reverse order?

Tags: c++

I'm newbie in c++ and i am doing some exercises.

I have a code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
int i=0;
int a,b,c;
a = i++;
b = i++;
c = i++;

cout << a << b << c;
return 0;
}
```

and, whe I run it, the result is: 012

But when I run it without variables a, b and c,
like in following code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
int i=0;
cout << i++ << i++ << i++;
return 0;
}
```

I get result in reverse order: 210

Why is this happening? I think it should be again 012 (I am using NetBeans)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout

Answer (score 1):

You are violating the rules of the language that has multiple increment and decrement in the same expression or as different arguments to the same call as undefined.