# Strange behavior in C++ compiler - Optimization?

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation, g++, g++4.8

I have a functions which returns `true` if the element is removed from the map, or `false` otherwise. Following is my function definition:

```
template <class Key, class Value>
bool HashMap<Key, Value>::remove(Key k)
{
  int result = map.erase(k);
  return (result == 1);
}
```

When I tried to check whether it is working or not, I found very strange behavior.

When I tried to print the results by using following syntax:

```
cout << boolalpha << students.remove("Sam") << " | " << students.remove("Sam") endl;
```

this printed `false | true` which should be `true | false` as per my knowledge. Then I tried to print it using another method:

```
bool b1 = students.remove("Sam");
bool b2 = students.remove("Sam");

cout << boolalpha << b1 << " | " << b2 << endl;
```

This printed the results as expected -> `true | false`. I guess this is a trick done by the compiler to optimize the code. But guesses aren't true always right ? (I am using `g++ 4.8.5` compiler)

Can anyone tell me what has happen here ?

Comment: disagree with this choice of duplicate really, the code is NOT undefined behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of argument evaluation during function calls in unspecified. [This applies to `std::cout` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout), because `std::cout << a << b;` is simply shorthand notation for

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, a), b);
```

Answer (score 4):

The order of evaluation is **unspecified** here (cfr. [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)) as in function calls (which actually is)

```
cout << boolalpha << students.remove("Sam") << " | " << students.remove("Sam") endl;
```

while is **defined** here

```
bool b1 = students.remove("Sam");
bool b2 = students.remove("Sam");

cout << boolalpha << b1 << " | " << b2 << endl;
```