# Why is this result?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is that about stack? I think the last `*p++` is undefined. `*p++` means `*(p++)` or `*p;p++;`?

```cpp
void test123()
{

    char s[] = "123", * p;
    p = s;
    // 1 2 3
    cout << *p++ << endl;
    cout << *p++ << endl;
    cout << *p++ << endl;

}
void test321()
{
    char s[] = "123", * p;
    p = s;
    //321
    cout << *p++ << *p++ << *p++ << endl;

}
int main(void)
{
    cout << "123:" << endl;
    test123();
    cout << "123:" << endl;
    test321();
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think the result is undefined.

Comment: _i think the result is undefined..._ Why do you think so?

Comment: but the result is not undefined !!! The reason i think result is undefined is p will be pointed unused memory affter using the last *p++

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of evaluation of arguments using std::cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout). Prior to c++17 evaluation order is undefined. Since c++17 it should be left to right.

Comment: if that is right,the result should be 231 when test123() return.,not 123

Answer (score 3):

`*p++` is evaluated to `*(p++)` according to operator precedence. And what `p++` does is that increments `p` by 1 and returns **the value before the increment**.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

> Post-increment and post-decrement creates a copy of the object, increments or decrements the value of the object and returns the copy from before the increment or decrement.

Even at the last line you mentioned, `p++` returns the position `s+2` so dereferencing it we get `3`, not the next address to it.

Except the order of evaluation(in `test321`), there is no undefined behavior in this code.

% If the expression was `*++p` it would do exactly what you said(However it is still not undefined since every string literal ends with zero(`\0`).

Answer (score 0):

`*p++` means `*(p++)` and `*p;p++`, because they are the same.

First `++` has a higher precedence over `*`, so it's computed first. Then dereferencement happens. In both cases. The thing is that `p++` returns the value before the increment, as explained in the C++ standard.

Finally, as it was said int he comments, in C++17, the evaluation order was improved so that `test321` behavior is well-defined. In C++11 it is indeed *not*.

The fact that `p` points to `\0` is also well defined in C++17 (it would also point to the same value in C++11 because you have 4 characters, not just 3). Even with an additional `++`, it would still be well-defined, unless you dereference the value. But just pointing to the end of an array is well defined as well and is why vectors can work.