# Why does the following code prints 12 11 10 13 and not 10 11 23 13

Tags: c++, operators, increment, cout

I came across a strange behavior while using increments operators in cout.
The code is supposed to print 10 11 12 13 but it prints in reverse. ie 12 11 10 13.

```
int y = 10;
cout << y++ << y++ << y++ << y;
```

I tried doing

```
cout << y++ << y-- << y++ << y;
```

and this works fine and print 10 11 10 11

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior). Basically the evaluation order for multiple increment or decrement operators on the same line is undefined.

Comment: Another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout