# I'm having trouble understanding how Post Increment (++), Pre Increment work together in an example

Tags: c++, operators, post-increment, pre-increment

I'm having trouble understanding how Post Increment (++), Pre Increment work together in an example.

x++ means add 1 to the variable
**But I am confused with this example:**

```
using namespace std;
/ run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
int main() {
    int a;
    a=8;
    cout<<++a<<a++<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I assume this means in first increased by 1 and in second it will first assign and then increment Which means the result should be 9 8 and 9  But when I compile it, I get 10 8 and 10. I don't understand.

Comment: Can you see the problem with a function call like `g(f(++a), a++)`?

Comment: How do you increment 8 twice and get 9?

Comment: if a = 8:
   `++a` => use 9 and remains 9
   `a++` => use 8 and remains 9

Comment: see also [here](/q/65218593), [here](/q/65218062), [here](/q/65214679), [here](/q/65213547), [here](/q/65202047), [here](/q/65201319), [here](/q/65197004), [here](/q/65196430), [here](/q/65195800), [here](/q/65194855), [here](/q/65194558), [here](/q/65194446), [here](/q/65194438), [here](/q/65194193)

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion has nothing to do with the pre- and post-increment, but with the evaluation order of the `operator <<`. There are plenty of threads on this, here is a good one imho: [SO discussion about evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout)

The summary is :

- Before C++17, if you have an expression such as `std::cout << f(a) << g(a) << std::endl;`, the order of evaluation (`f` first or `g` first) is not specified.

This becomes clearer when we look at what the expression above means. For the overloaded `operator<<`, it effectively becomes

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, f(a)), g(a));
so: 
function  (<--------- arg 1 --------->,<arg2>)
```

In this case, the evaluation is unsequenced, and it is not defined whether arg1 or arg2 will be evaluated first.

- With C++17, the order is specified from left to right.

From `[n4659] §8.2.2 : 5`

> If an operator function is invoked using operator notation, argument evaluation is sequenced as specified for the built-in operator.

I interpret this as follows: even if the operator is overloaded, **if** it is called as an operator (i.e. `std::cout << f(a) << g(a) << std::endl;`), it will effectively be evaluated as

```
std::cout.operator<<(f(a)).operator<<(g(a)).operator<<(std::endl);
```

However, if the call is made explicitely as

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, f(a)), g(a));
```

it will be treated as a function call and the order is still not specified.

- To be safe, you are better off splitting up your prints/evaluations in separate statements (i.e. separated by `;`) unless you have a good reason not to (and know the details well), especially since different operators behave differently (e.g. `+` remains unsequenced after C++17).

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks for the feedback! If `f` and `g` return `int`, they would be chained though, not nested, right? Since `std::cout << f(a);` == `std::cout.operator(f(a));`. For custom types, that would be different.

Comment: Yeah, probably true, I just noticed how many others there are, could just delete mine.

Comment: @Bathsheba : Done. To be honest, now that I looked more into it, it's not clear to me why for the `int` case the order is not specified. After all, I would expect `std::cout << int(2) << int(3);` to be equal to `std::cout.operator(int(2)).operator(int(3));` even before C++17. For non-inbuilt types, that's a different story.