# c++ when reference variable's value change?

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

int foo1(int &n);
int foo2(int n);

int main() {
    int n1, n2;
    cout << foo1(n1) << n1 << foo2(n2) << endl;
}

int foo1(int &n) {
    n = 3;
    return 1;
}

int foo2(int n) {
    return 2;
}
```

and I get output `1 (trash val) 2`.

Why `n1`'s value is not modified? `foo1()` is worked faster than `cout << n1;`?
When reference var's value modified?

Comment: Please state which language standard you are working to: `c++17` or... ?

Comment: I suppose that you are using MSVC of c++14 or older, since I've spotted the same problem once, and it turned out that the order of calculation in a single sentence cannot be guaranteed before c++17.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of evaluation of arguments using std::cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout) And take a look at the [second answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361541/5105949). Pre C++17 the behaiour is unspecified.

Comment: thank you. I'm using c++11 and I understand! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
cout << foo1(n1)<<n1<<foo2(n2)<<2ndl;
```

actually resolves to

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, foo(n1)), n1), foo2(n2)), endl);
```

The order of arguments evaluation is not defined by the standard. It's an implementation dependent. So here

```
operator<<(operator<<(cout, foo(n1)), n1)
```

either can be evaluated first. And in your case it appears `n1` took the first place and then `operator<<(cout, foo(n1))`