# Number raised to 2, 3, and 4

Tags: c++, operators, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, compound-assignment

I have written the following simple C++ program to output the powers of a number input by the user to indices 2, 3, and 4:

```
int a = 0;

cin >> a;

int a2 = a * a;

cout << "\n" << a2 << "\n" << (a2 *= a) << "\n" << (a2 *= a) << "\n";

return 0;
```

The output for `a = 2` was

```
16
16
16
```

Can anybody explain why that is?

Comment: IIRC there's no sequencing in the expression `cout << "\n" << a2 << "\n" << (a2 *= a) << "\n" << (a2 *= a) << "\n"`.  You try to modify a variable twice without sequencing, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: 99% of the time someone says their code would be "simple", it is super complicated. Mixing computations with output is not "simple" it is complicated. Don't mix them and the issue will be gone

Comment: Which version of the standard do you use? The rules regarding sequencing when ``operator<<`` is involved have changed after c++14 (if I remember correctly) .

Comment: See dupe: [Order of evaluation of arguments using std::cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout) and [What are sequence points, and how do they relate to undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/what-are-sequence-points-and-how-do-they-relate-to-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I know other ways to accomplish the same result, but I have just tried this one and got an unexpected output, so I asked out of mere curiosity.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you mean that the program essentially performs all instances of `a2 *= a` then it outputs the value of `a2` to the stream?

Comment: no worries. I just wanted to point out that, even with a bit of experience in c++, I do not consider this code "simple". When I see this code in the wild, I wouldnt know what output to expect. Even with c++17 where the output is defined (as explained in the answer), I find the code difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich Yes, the answer to my question confirms that.

Comment: A less confusing variation would be `cout << "\n" << a2 << "\n" << (a2 * a) << "\n" << (a2 * a2) << "\n";`

Comment: Both gcc and clang emit a warning about the original code: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fo66MTK48). It's usually a good idea to enable all warnings `-Wall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody explain why that is?

This is because you are using a C++ compiler that supports C++14, or earlier.

Before C++17 the evaluation order for the following expression is not specified by the C++ standard:

```
cout << "\n" << a2 << "\n" << (a2 *= a) << "\n" << (a2 *= a) << "\n";
```

C++14, and earlier, allows the C++ compiler to implement any evaluation order for this expression. Before C++17 it was allowed (but not required), for both `a2 *= a` expressions to be evaluated first, setting `a2` to `16`, in the end, which gets `cout`ed three times.

As a general rule of thumb: unless the evaluation order is specified it is entirely up to your compiler to evaluate the expression in any order. For example, with `int x=foo() + bar();` either `foo()` or `bar()` may be called first, followed by the other one. The order of evaluation of `+`'s operands is not specified by the C++ standard. Your expression using `<<` operators is the same thing.

Before C++17 the above statement may produce different output with different C++ compilers, depending on which evaluation order they chose. It is entirely up to them.

Starting with C++17 the evaluation order here is specified, and you will get the intuitively expected results.

Comment: Now it is all clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: Now how to close this thread?

Comment: The part "Before C++17 it was allowed (but not required), for both `a2 *= a` expressions to be evaluated first" is at least misleading if not wrong. Since `a2` undergoes two unsequenced modifications (before C++17), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is incorrect in describing what happened before C++17.    Before C++11, the two sub-expressions `(a2 *= a)` are evaluated, and modify `a2` without intervening sequence points, so behaviour is undefined.  From C++11 and before C++17, evaluation of the the two sub-expressions `(a2 *= a)` are unsequenced, so behaviour is undefined   (differently worded descriptions, same outcome of undefined behaviour).   The undefined behaviour has nothing to do with (in fact trumps) any consideration of unspecified evaluation order.